# Ребят, помогите советом

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios

Проблема в следующем: в одном разделе сайта мне нужно скрывать/показывать определенные блоки, сохранять работу таймера и т.д. и чтобы все это работало не смотря на перезагрузку страницы. Для этого запись в localstorage и как бы все работает. Но, как всегда найдется умник, который залезит куда надо и сделает пакость. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть еще варианты хранения таких данных чтобы со стороны клиента не было возможности повлиять на эти данные? И самое главное чтобы это без проблем работало на андроид и ios т.к. покопавшись в гугле, то все что работает на пк не всегда работает на мобильных устройствах. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Любые данные, хранимые локально у пользователя, пользователь может (и имеет право) изменять. Вместо попыток сделать невозможное, следует адекватно построить клиент-серверное взаимодействие - и не хранить локально те данные, которые не принадлежат пользователю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серверный рендеринг Вам в помощь. Самые популярные сейчас это PHP и Node. Данные можно хранить скажем в MySQL, и по значениям из БД отображать/скрывать определённые блоки.